# How can I store a value in my global variable and use it inside any method anywhere in activity

Tags: java, android, variables, scope

I am trying to build a weather app.I have an API link which I am taking as String variable whose scope is global  and I have another method by which I obtain longitude and latitude. I want to save these latitude and longitude values in my variable whose scope is global. While I am inside my geocoder method where I am taking out latitude and longitude values (my global variable API link changes and gives me the desired result because I am concatenating longtiude and latitude with my variable whose scope is global. But once I go out of this method and try using my API link in a different method (I loose the values latitude and longitude I had obtained and concatenated in geocoder method hoping that it would permanently change my global variable value.

Here is the code. (I have 4-5 files but I am pasting only main activity code where I am actually working) If I hardcode the latitude and longitude values I am getting the desired results but I am just trying to get better at this by obtaining latitude and longitude.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Model>> {

    public static final int WEATHERLOADER = 1;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    WeatherAdapter mAdapter;
    List<Model> modelList;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocation;
    String latitude;
    String longit;
    Button getweather;


   String APILINK = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=";
         
    String APIKEY = "&appid=5c161192e5aa828fc6a8896eddaf89e2";
   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getweather = findViewById(R.id.getWeather);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        modelList = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new WeatherAdapter(this, modelList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        ConnectivityManager conn = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conn!=null) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = conn.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (networkInfo!=null){
                LoaderManager loaderManager = getSupportLoaderManager();
                loaderManager.initLoader(WEATHERLOADER, null, this);
            }

        }


        fusedLocation = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        getweather.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                    wantLocation();
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 44);
                }

            }


        });


    }

    private void wantLocation() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }


        fusedLocation.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {

                Location location = task.getResult();

                if (location != null) {

                    try {


                        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(
                                MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

                        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

                        /*cityname.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#6200EE'><b>City Name:</b><br></font>" + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea()));
                        longtitude.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#6200EE'><b>Longtitude:</b><br></font>" + addresses.get(0).getLongitude()));
                        lattitude.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#6200EE'><b>Lattitude:</b><br></font>" + addresses.get(0).getLatitude()));
                        countryname.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#6200EE'><b>Country Name:</b><br></font>" + addresses.get(0).getCountryName()));
*/

                        APILINK = APILINK + addresses.get(0).getLatitude() + "&lon=" + addresses.get(0).getLongitude() + APIKEY;

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }


        });


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<List<Model>> onCreateLoader(int i, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(APILINK), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        return new WeatherLoader(this, APILINK);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<List<Model>> loader, List<Model> modelList) {
        if (modelList!=null && !modelList.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter = new WeatherAdapter(this, modelList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<List<Model>> loader) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. There are no global variables in Java. Everything is class-scoped.

Comment: So what should I do sir? I am sorry if my wording wasnt clear. What I meant to say was "the scope of my variable is global" and I want to concatenate some values to the variable whose scope is global.

Comment: The scope of your variable is class scope. I'vew already told you that. If by any chance you mean `static` and/or `public` you should say so.

Comment: I was not asking for whats the scope of variable.

Comment: No, you were *mis-stating* the scope of your variable. 'Global' is a scope. A scope that doesn't exist in Java. You need to clarify your question so it makes sense.

Comment: I see I am sorry now can you help me to solve this problem

Comment: Not until you clarify your question. It is about global variables in Java, which don't exist, so your question isn't about anything real. Try again.

Comment: I did corrected my question sir.

Comment: You have changed it but not corrected it. The title continues to refer to a global variable, and now the body of your question refers to 'global scope', which, as I have now told you four times. does not exist in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question/situation entirely, but from the code provided it looks like *APILINK* should be correctly modified in the *onComplete* method. If you are trying to access *APILINK* from a different class, you could create a "getter" method, which when called, returns APILINK:

```
public String getAPILINK() {
    return APILINK;
}
```

By setting a String equal to *getAPILINK()*, you can make a copy of *APILINK* in different classes or methods.

Edit 1:
To concatenate Strings, you simply use the *+* operator as you did. This likely means the problem lies elsewhere. To troubleshoot, try adding

```
System.out.println(APILINK);
```

to various points in the program, like before calling *onComplete* and after.
If "&lon=" and *APIKEY* were appended, but not the latitude and longitude, then the problem is retrieving those values.

Comment: first of all many thanks for your answer. Yes, I have broken the API link. And I want to get the values of longitude and latitude and store them in a String variable and then combine the API link String and the longitude and latitude variables (concatenate) and get a new modified URL.